# Hamburger rendering bug in CSS

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me flip the position of the hamburger menu and the text on the left. Tried doing it multiple times but failed. I have tried using Z-Index to change the position but didn't seem to help.
Final Image on my website is as attached. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I also want to change the hamburger from a normal bar to a circle icon. Would be great if I could get some assistance for what I described.

Code:

```css
.moreoptions{
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
   
}



.middle {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
    top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    /*background-color: #38618c;*/
    background-color: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease-in, transform 0.4s ease-in,
    width 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!--- Hamburger-->
<div class ="moreoptions">
    <h1> More Options </h1>
</div>
<label for="myInput">
    <span class="bar top"></span>
    <span class="bar middle"></span>
    <span class="bar bottom"></span>
</label>
```

[image: Image Rendered]

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of answers:

1. The icon can be positioned on the left by simply re-arranging your HTML. See the below example code for how the HTML could be re-written.
2. Unfortunately, z-index does not work in the way that you need. It only controls the **stacking** order of overlapping elements, and not the flow of layout. Wrapping your 'button' up in a single element that has floating or flex children is the way to go. Don't forget to clearfix if your use floats.
3. I've included a minimal example of how you might transition from the hamburger icon to a close icon, [see it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Ilkai/pen/rNaYRXR?editors=1100). To achieve a morph from a hamburger to a circle icon (guessing with an `x` in the middle?), there are many options, the most basic being stacking the two different icons, and transitioning `opacity` on toggle with CSS.

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle" class="btn menu--btn">
    <div class="icon icon--menu">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    More Options
  </label>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</nav>
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;

  transition: color 150ms ease,
    background-color 150ms ease,
    border-color 150ms ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #999;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555;
  border-color: #000;
}

.icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.icon--menu {
  padding: 6px 4px;
}

.icon--menu > div {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  transition: background-color 150ms ease,
    transform 200ms ease,
    opacity 200ms linear;
}

.icon--menu > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn .icon--menu > div:nth-child(1) {
  transform:  translateY(5px) rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn .icon--menu > div:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn .icon--menu > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform:  translateY(-5px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your immediate concern of positioning the hamburger to the left:

HTML:

```
<label for="myInput">
   <span class="bar top"></span>
   <span class="bar middle"></span>
   <span class="bar bottom"></span>
</label>
<div class="moreoptions">
   <h1>More Options</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.moreoptions {
  padding-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  /*background-color: #38618c;*/
  background-color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-in, transform 0.4s ease-in,
    width 0.4s ease-in;
}
```